# DataGrid Paging in C# (With Next & Previous Link )

Tags: c#, datagrid, paging

I have a Data Grid holding upto 250 rows with unquie column called Tab order. Now i need to 
have only 5 rows and remaining rows should only be visbile when i click on next button and so on ..

below is my code snippet, when the for loop is completed it will load up all 250 row data into data grid .. i need to implement paging concept here can any one help out in guiding me in right path

Thanks in advance

code snippet :

```
private void buttonUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadFile(pdfFullPath, txtPassword.Text);

            form = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
            java.util.List FieldTypes = form.getFields();

            formFieldCount = FieldTypes.size();
            totalPages = document.getNumberOfPages();

            ///cmbpage --- Code pasted here 
            ArrayList lstPages = new ArrayList();
            ArrayList lstTabs = new ArrayList();
            ArrayList lstNames = new ArrayList();
            ArrayList lstTypes = new ArrayList();

            if (formFieldCount != 0)
            {
               int formField = 1; 
                for (int i = 0; i < formFieldCount; i++)
                {
                    pdfFields = (PDField)form.getFields().get(i);
                    fieldName = pdfFields.getFullyQualifiedName();

                    FieldType type = new FieldType();
                    if (pdfFields is PDTextbox)
                    {
                        type = FieldType.Text;
                        System.String iAsString = Integer.toString(formField);
                        pdfFields.setValue(iAsString);

                    }

                    else if (pdfFields is PDCheckbox)
                    {
                        type = FieldType.CheckBox;
                        System.String iAsString = Integer.toString(formField);
                        checkBoxList.Add(fieldName, formField);
                    }
                    else if (pdfFields is PDRadioCollection)
                    {
                        type = FieldType.RadioButton;
                        System.String iAsString = Integer.toString(formField);
                        radioButtonsList.Add(fieldName, formField);
                    }
                    else if (pdfFields is PDPushButton)
                    {
                        type = FieldType.PushButton;
                        System.String iAsString = Integer.toString(formField);
                    }

                        DataRow newRow = availableFieldsTable.NewRow();              
                        newRow["Field Type"] = type;
                        newRow["Tab Order"] = formField;
                        newRow["Field Name"] = fieldName;

                        availableFieldsTable.Rows.Add(newRow);  --> adds up data in data grid                
                    formField++;
                }

             }

            document.save(dummyPDFPath);
        }
```

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/67520/GridView-Paging-and-Sorting

Answer (score 0):

DataGrid will look like this:

```
<asp:datagrid id=DataGrid1 runat="server" PageSize="5" GridLines="Vertical"
CellPadding="3" BackColor="White" BorderWidth="1px" BorderStyle="None"
BorderColor="#999999" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="True"
DataSource="" Height="64px" Width="120px" AllowPaging="True"
DataMember="MeetingMinutes">
//whatever here..
</Datagrid>
```

If you want next and previous to navigate ,

```
<PagerSettings Mode="NextPrevious" NextPageText="Next"
 PreviousPageText="Previous" />
```

This could be used if you want first and last tab to display the first and last page.

```
<PagerSettings FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last"
 Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast" NextPageText="Next" PreviousPageText="Previous" />
```

This is a 
Once the event PageIndexChanging is executed, the event will be fired for PageIndexChanged paging. In this event, you can safely bind the grid again to access the second page. It is always preferable to cache the data used to bind the data source.

protected void DataGrid_PageIndexChanging(object sender, DataGridPageEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGrid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            BindData();
        }